# ¿Porque WPF consume tantos recursos?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy aprendiendo a programar aplicaciones WPF y me estoy dando cuenta que consumen una gran cantidad de recursos (Sobretodo RAM). Como ejemplo una aplicación WPF recién creada con la ventana en blanco consume 75 MB y con elementos dentro he llegado a hacer un programa que consume hasta 300MB siendo una aplicación bastante simple.

La preguta es porque ocurre esto y si hay alguna manera de arreglarlo ya que simplemente mirando el consumo de otras aplicaciones que tengo dentro de mi PC me doy cuenta de que el uso de RAM es escesivo para cosas tan absurdas como las que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Gran cantidad de recursos? Comparado con qué? En qué te basas para dar ese diagnóstico? Ahorita estoy usando chrome con sólo 4 pestañas abiertas, y si me voy al Task Manager, chrome está utilizando más de 600MB de RAM. Has escuchado el dicho *"Unused RAM is wasted RAM"*? Ya investigaste los recursos que utiliza el SO para iniciar una app de WPF? Ya investigaste el "peso" de las liberías gráficas cargadas?... Ya revisaste si tienes recursos COM que no estás desechando correctamente? Ya sabes si tienes "memory leaks"? *"Cómo lo arreglo?"*... Revisando cómo utilizas los recursos dentro de tu app.

Comment: @Arriel me baso en que la misma aplicación hecha con Windows forms no llega a consumir 30 MB. Y estoy bastante seguro de que no tengo fugas de memoria

Comment: La verdad si consume un poco más que, por ejemplo, Windows Forms pero es solo en ámbitos de desarrollo, por temas de debugging, pero una vez compilado su demanda baja, claramente no al nivel de Forms porque es otra tecnología, son otros ensamblados, Forms se valía mucho del propio windows, por otra parte, WPF obtiene sus recursos de varios lugares. Piensa que para que WPF funcione debe cargar en memoria varios ensamblados del NET Framework, Forms con un puñado ya anda solo. En mi experiencia usando WPF para un ERP grande nunca tuve ese problema.